# Prove: If $b\in$ Range($A$), then $b \not\in$ Null($A^T$).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R^{m \times n}}$full rank, and let $b\in \mathbb{R^m}$ with $ b \neq 0$.

Prove: If $b\in$ Range($A$), then $b \not\in$ Null($A^T$).

I need help with the proof.

**pf**

Assume $A \in \mathbb{R^{m \times n}}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R^m}$ with $ b \neq 0$.

Let $b \in$Range(A).

Suppose $Ax \in N(A^T)$,

then $(A^TA)x=0$.

By definition of column space of A,

$Ax \in$ Range($A$).

So, $Ax \perp Ax$.

$\Rightarrow Ax=0 \Rightarrow x=0$

Since A has rank $n$, $\Rightarrow$ rank($A^TA$) $= n$

Thus $A^TA$ is invertible, and $b\not\in$Nul($A^T$).

Comment: Your proof is messy and could have stopped at $Ax=0\implies x=0$, for that means $b=0$; contradiction. You don't need the last two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b=Ax $ and $A^Tb=0$, you have $A^TAx=0$. Then  $$0=x^TA^TAx=(Ax)^TAx=b^Tb, $$ and so $b=0$.